# How do I turn this list into a string?

Tags: python, binary, decimal, ascii

I'm trying to convert binary to decimal to ASCII. Using this code, I'm able to take a binary input and split it into chunks of 7 bits.

```
def binary_to_ascii7bits(bstring):
    n = 7
    byte = [bstring[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(bstring), n)]
    print(byte)
```

I need to be able to turn each 7-bit substring into a decimal number in order to use the chr function. If I try to turn this list into a string, it prints for example, "['1111000']", but I cannot have the brackets and apostrophes in the string. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you give example input?

Comment: `print('\n'.join(byte))`?

Comment: You do know that ASCII characters below 32 are essentially non printable (some of them being print controls such as tab and new line) so your output may look weird depending on the binary string provided.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for the `chr` function it should be an integer, not a decimal.

Add this list comprehension before the print function -

```
byte = [chr(64 + int(i)) for i in byte]
```

This will give the string for the bytes. I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add just one more line (as below) to achieve what you described.

You have `int(..., 2)` to convert the string representation of a binary number into an integer. Then apply `chr` to get a character. This procedure is done using (list) comprehension, so that the result is a list of characters. Then use `join` to make a single string.

```py
text = '1111000' * 10

def binary_to_ascii7bits(bstring):
    n = 7
    byte = [bstring[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(bstring), n)]
    return ''.join(chr(int(x, 2)) for x in byte)

print(binary_to_ascii7bits(text)) # xxxxxxxxxx
```